# Vista crashes with blue screen

Tags: windows-vista, crash, netbios

A friend of mine has Vista and it has been crashing for quite some time.

He gets a regular crash with blue screen and a message that goes like "disable netbios caching" (it goes bye so fast i can't get the whole message) then it reboots.

Me thinks it has something to do with CCleaner but he insists that this never happened before. He's been using this program for quite some time but i still think this program does too much tweaking (often unnecessary).

Comment: Use bluescreen view on that pc to get the bug check code and post it...http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html

Answer (score 1):

Generate a full minidump of the memory, http://support.microsoft.com/kb/969028, then go and find where the crash happened in it win Widnows debugging tools http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009

Comment: Thank you ascarb! Shall look into your tips. In the mean time, i did find an article in this site about disabling the Netbios on Vista. My friend has done so. It may be too soon to tell, but it seems to be doing good so far.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the system error logs to see what the system thinks is happening? Especially with a BSOD, your computer has time to write an error log before it reboots, so this is likely to give a good indicator of the problem.

Also, CCleaner isn't a terrible app. I use it myself for many situations. However, it is possible to do damage with it. I just wouldn't go pointing at it unless I'd done some footwork first.

Comment: It's good to hear from someone who has some good experiences with CCleaner. Perhaps i was too harsh on this program.

Comment: I don't like that it only cleans user temp files in the profile it is run in. I wish it at least had the option to clear all user profile temp files when run in an admin account. Cleanup! by Steven Gould only cleans all temp files it can access, and doesn't have the option to only clean those in your own profile. So I choose which one I need and run from there. I also use CCleaners registry cleaner, which works pretty well. I don't use the other functions because I have other tools that do a better job.